# XCT Testing of IBActions and IBOutlets Swift (Optionals)

Tags: swift, unit-testing, option-type, xctest

I am wondering what is the best way to test IBOutlets and IBActions in Swift due to IBActions being Optionals.

I am currently rewriting a project I originally wrote in Swift but this time I want to use XCT Unit Testing.

I have already run into a small problem regarding the testing of IBOutlets and IBActions. Here is my code:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    mainMenuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainMenuViewController") as! MainMenuViewController

    let dummy = mainMenuViewController.view // force loading subviews and setting outlets

    mainMenuViewController.viewDidLoad()
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func testWhetherTranslationGameModeButtonExists() {
    XCTAssert(mainMenuViewController.translateButton != nil, "translate button should exist at all times");
}

func testWhetherTranslateGameModeButtonTitleIsCorrect() {

    let title: String? = mainMenuViewController.translateButton?.titleLabel?.text

    if let unwrappedTitle = title {
        XCTAssertTrue(unwrappedTitle == "Translate Mode", "title of translate button should be Translate Mode")
    }
    else {
        XCTFail("Value isn't set")
    }
}

func testTranslateGameModeButtonIBAction() {

    if let unwrappedButton = mainMenuViewController.translateButton {
        if let actions: Array<String> = unwrappedButton.actionsForTarget(mainMenuViewController, forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) as? Array<String> {

            contains(actions, "")
            XCTAssertTrue(contains(actions, "translateButtonPressed"), "translate button should call method translateButtonPressed")
        }
        else {
            XCTFail("button is set but the IBAction is not set")
        }
    }
    else {
        XCTFail("button isn't set and therefore IBAction can not function")
    }
}
```

As you can see, the first test checks to see whether the translate game mode button exists. This works fine.

However with the title test I need to unwrap the button and then test the label. This seems like two tests in one.

I have the same issue when it comes to the IBAction. I need to unwrap the optional type to use the button and have a XCTAssert for the success and the failure. Therefore every time I use this button I will need to unwrap it before I can use it. This seems very repetitive and again seems like multiple tests in one.

I am wondering if this is the correct approach, or is there a better way to approach the testing of optionals.

Comment: i get error while setting this storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)?? when i changed to  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType))..it works..do you know why this is happening

Comment: I am getting the same error when I use NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)). Not sure why yet.

Comment: nope i mean i get error when i set bundle to nil?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, go to XCode 7.
Using XCode 7, you can easily do UI tests:

File -> new -> target -> iOS -> Test iOS UI Testing bundle

The generated code has some hints how to use it. Basically you place the cursor in your test method and then hit the red record button.

So you can simulate (almost) any user action. The generated code is more readable, when you name the UI elements for accessibility.

Your test result are way more meaningful, since you are testing your controllers in their natural habitat: inside your application.

(it has been possible before XCode 7 but with XCode 7 it's really easy to do)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your button is optional.
If you create the outlet in your controller by dragging it, you get a non optional variable

I am setting up my Controller test like this:
https://gist.github.com/racer1988/bf15448efde47e627dac

I took the idea from:
http://natashatherobot.com/ios-testing-view-controllers-swift/

And then in order to do complete coverage you write 3 tests:

- if a outlet is set
- if a outlet is connected to a action
- if the action is doing its job

This way you are testing everything, without the need to fake a tap or something like that

```
func testOutletExist() {
    XCTAssertNotNil(viewController.outletName)
}

func testActionIsConnected() {
    XCTAssertTrue(viewController.outlet.action == "IBactionName:")
}

func testActionCode() {
    let result = IBactionName()
    XCTAssertSomething(result)
}
```

Comment: Marco, where on earth did you find outlet.action? I wish it existed

Comment: @JulioBailon Sorry in the example I was testing the menu bar 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/action